# Falha de Compilação - 'okhttp-3.14.0.jar'

Tags: android-studio

Porventura, alguém já deparou com erro deste:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
 > Failed to transform file 'okhttp-3.14.0.jar' to match attributes 
    {artifactType=android-dex, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=16} using 
    transform DexingTransform
 > Error while dexing.
```

Agradeço antecipadamente!

Comment: Ola @Caue, bem vindo ao SOpt, percebi lendo seu comentário que você achou uma solução para seu problema diferente das propostas pela comunidade. Se você adicionar uma resposta mostrando como você resolveu seria de grande ajuda para as pessoas da comunidade que tiverem o mesmo problema. Não esqueça de dar uma olhada em nosso [Tour].  =D

Comment: Tomei os seguintes passos: 1- CLICK "FILE" ; 2- CLICK NA PASTA "APP"; 3- CLICK  COM BOTÃO ESQUERDO OU CLICK F4; MUDE SOURCE COMPATIBILITY  E TARGET COMPATIBILITY PARA VERSÃO 1.8, REFENTE AO JAVA INSTALADO.

Answer (score 0):

Importe o arquivo `okhttp-3.14.0.jar`, caso ele possua dependências também importe as dependências, para `libs`.

No arquivo `build.gradle`:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    // Adicione essa linha e mantenha as já existentes
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])

}
```

PS: Eu estava lendo a documentação do `OkHttp` e ele é dependente do `Okio` na própria página do `OkHttp` tem o link do `Okio`. Caso não o tenha baixado, baixe o jar contendo o `Okio` e importe em `libs`.

Comment: MUITO OBRIGADO POR RESPONDER, CONSEGUIR RESOLVER ADICIONANDO ESSA LINHA NO GRADLE:  compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8